# Publish wp post when a event is created

Tags: civievent

Is there a way to create a WordPress post with Civi event shortcode when an event is created in Civi?

Any WordPress plugin or Civi extension that would do the job?

Comment: Don't know of anything that does what you ask, but obviously it would show up in in event listings from eg [ux_event_listing](https://github.com/agileware/wp-civicrm-ux/blob/master/USAGE.md#event-listing-shortcode)

Comment: There's a plugin to synch from WP to Civi you could take a look at (not sure how/if it works with Gutenberg etc.) but worth checking out https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser